# Ansible Playbook | Need to execute powershell script

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I am wondering if someone can help. I am trying to find a way to run a powershell script within an ansible playbook.

I found a module that seems to allow it but I am unable to make it work.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_powershell_module.html

The PS script that I need to run within the ansible playbook is the following:

```
# Step 1
$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
$net.MapNetworkDrive("X:", "\\fileserver", $true, $USER, $PASS)

Copy-Item "x:\*" -Destination c:\scripts -recurse -force

# Replace user and run installer
$GenericPath = "C:\pts\Install.bat"
$name = (Get-Content C:\pts\file.txt)
$pos = $name.IndexOf("@")
$User = $name.Substring(0, $pos)
#$Domain = $name.Substring($pos+1)

if ($name -match 'dom1.al.com')
{
$Domain = "al"
}
if ($name -match 'dom2.al.com')
{
$Domain = "al2"
}
if ($name -match 'dom3.al.com')
{
$Domain = "al3"
}
if ($name -match 'dom4.al.com')
{
$Domain = "al4"
}

$ReplaceUser = $Domain + '\' + $User
(Get-Content $GenericPath) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "ReplaceUser","$ReplaceUser"} | Set-Content $GenericPath

F:\pts\reconfigure.bat
```

Can someone please let me know how should the ansible playbook needs to look like in order to get this to work. The target VMs where the PS will be executed via ansible are Windows OS. I understand I can run PS directly on those servers but the execution for this workflow needs to happen from within an ansible playbook.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit better the question?
Don't have enough data to provide a solution.
Ansible Control Host may need to be Linux, you need to configure WinRM for getting access via Ansible after which you can use this module for run your poweshell script.

Comment: I don't see any attempt to write an ansible playbook in your above question. What have you tried so far? What is unclear in the documentation you linked? What is the actual error or specific problem you have?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it worked with RHEL, so the same might work in Windoze.  Try this:

```
---
- name: Run PowerShell script
  hosts: all
  become: no
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - win_shell: "{{ item }}"
    with_file:
    - my_kewel_powershell_script.ps
...
```